# Unexpected ElasticSearch shard allocation for a single replica with allocation disabled

Tags: elasticsearch, sharding

We have a two node environment and there is certain data that we only want to store on the master node (as the other node is not highly available).

To do this, I've set the number of replicas to 0 and also set the following properties on the indices for which we do not want shard allocation to occur:

```
"index.routing.allocation.enable": "none",
"index.routing.allocation.rebalance": "none"
```

My expectation here is that doing so will keep all 5 shards on the master node. However, as soon as I connect the worker node to the environment, 2 or 3 of the shards from each index are moved over to the worker node! How can I stop this from happening and keep all of the shards for the specified index on the master node? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to shard allocation filtering to specify which nodes are allowed to host the shards of a particular index.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/shard-allocation-filtering.html